# C# WebMethod - Enviar e Receber um mesmo objeto (custom) via Parametro

Tags: javascript, c#, json, webmethods

Meu código:

Objeto:

```
public class Person
{

    private string _Nome;
    private DateTime _Nascimento;

    public string Nome { get { return _Nome; } }
    public DateTime Nascimento { get { return _Nascimento; } }

    public Person(string Nome, DateTime Nascimento)
    {
        _Nome = Nome;
        _Nascimento = Nascimento;
    }

}
```

Minha Pagina (WebMethods):

```
[WebMethod]
public static Person SendPerson()
{
    return new Person("Jhon Snow", DateTime.Now);
}

[WebMethod]
public static string ReceivePerson(Person oPerson)
{
    return "OK!";
}
```

Meu Javascript:

```
var Person;
GetPerson();
SendPersonBack();
function GetPerson()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "frmVenda.aspx/SendPerson",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (RequestReturn) {
            Person = RequestReturn.d;
            console.log(Person);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
function SendPersonBack()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "frmVenda.aspx/ReceivePerson",
        data: JSON.stringify({"oPerson": Person}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (RequestReturn) {
            alert(RequestReturn.d);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Imagem Recebendo o objeto normal mas erro ao enviar de volta]

O objeto é enviado normalmente ao clientside, mas ao recebê-lo de volta no Servidor, não dá certo!
o objeto é o mesmo que eu enviei, são as mesmas propriedades.

Por que não consigo recebê-lo de volta?
Onde está o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um construtor sem parâmetros, setando todas as propriedades para string e adicionando o método set em todas as propriedades.

Isso fez com que o .net reconhecesse o objeto vindo via ajax e populasse as propriedades normalmente sem erros.

```
public class Person
    {

        private string _Nome;
        private string _Nascimento;

        public string Nome { get { return _Nome; } set { _Nome = value; } }
        public string Nascimento { get { return _Nascimento; } set { _Nascimento= value; } }

        public Person()
        {

        }

        public Person(string Nome, DateTime Nascimento)
        {
            _Nome = Nome;
            _Nascimento = Nascimento.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acho que você deveria serializar. O problema que o que o seu jquery envia de volta, pode estar se perdendo. Eu trabalho de forma parecida, mas uso a serialização para fazêlo. Veja abaixo um exemplo meu. Na minha controller eu tenho um método que executa uma LINQ. O resultado dessa LINQ, eu serializo e envio para minha função jquery. Veja a controller: Observe que eu retorno um JSon.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PreencheCargo(int _resp)
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var result_responsavel = db.Responsavel
                .Where(w => w.IDResponsavel == _resp)
                .Join(db.Nivel_Responsavel, r => r.IDNivel_Responsavel, n => n.IDNivel_Responsavel, (r, n) => new { r, n })
                .Join(db.Responsavel_Motivo, rm => rm.r.IDResponsavel, m => m.IDResponsavel, (rm, m) => new { rm, m })
                .Join(db.Responsavel_Unidade_Negocio, rn => rn.rm.r.IDResponsavel, un => un.IDResponsavel, (rn, un) => new { rn, un })
                .Join(db.Responsavel_TipoPDV, rtp => rtp.rn.rm.r.IDResponsavel, tp => tp.IDResponsavel, (rtp, tp) => new { rtp, tp})
                .Join(db.TipoPDV, tpdv => tpdv.tp.IDTipoPDV, tdv => tdv.IDTipoPDV, (tpdv, tdv) => new { tpdv, tdv})
                .Select(s => new { s.tpdv.rtp.rn.rm.r.IDResponsavel, s.tpdv.rtp.rn.rm.r.NM_Responsavel, s.tpdv.rtp.rn.rm.r.NM_Responsavel_Sigla, 
                                   s.tpdv.rtp.rn.rm.r.IDNivel_Responsavel,s.tpdv.rtp.un.Unidade_Negocio, s.tpdv.rtp.rn.m.Motivo, s.tdv.IDTipoPDV, s.tdv.Descricao }).ToList();

            return Json(new { result_responsavel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Dessa forma agora eu tenho um objeto no outro lado, bit a bit, que o jquery vai desserealizar e trabalhar com o objeto reconstruído. A minha função jquery, retorna para o meu método da mesma forma, porem eu defino um parâmetro para passar para a controller. Acho que isso não é problema, mas comigo faço assim. Veja abaixo minha jquery.

```
function CarregaDadosCargo(ajaxParameter) {

    $.ajax({

        url: '/CadastroCargo/PreencheCargo',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({_resp: ajaxParameter}),
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                $('#txtResponsavel').val(itemData.NM_Responsavel);
                $('#txtSigla').val(itemData.NM_Responsavel_Sigla);
                $('#cbxNivelResp option[value=' + itemData.IDNivel_Responsavel + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            })
        },
        error: function(error){
    }
    })
}
```

Não sei se isso irá resolver seu problema, mas comigo não tenho esse tipo de problemas.

Comment: sim, eu poderia recebê-lo  de volta no server como json string  e converte-lo para o objeto Person. Mas eu não queria ter que fazer isso, sabendo que o objeto que eu envio é o mesmo que eu estou recebendo. Queria entender o por quê do erro.